# Icecast - list clients on web directory

Tags: icecast

I try to show list logged listeners to stream outside admin area. Without success.

I coppied listclients.xsl  from /admin directory to /web. 
I created sym link in /usr/share/icecast2/web. I can open: 
 radio_adres.com:8000/listclients.xsl?mount=/mount_name.ogg
 and its    look this same   as  page: 
  radio_adres.com:8000/admin/listclients.xsl?mount=/mount_name.ogg 
 except one. There is no listeners list.

`<xsl:value-of select="@mount"/ >`shows stream name, and  `<xsl:value-of select="@listeners" />` number of logged, but loop which is in original file to show listeners `<xsl:for-each select="listener"></xsl:for-each>` not working.

I have 3 log level but there is no error or even warning. Nothing. Maybe icecast don't allow show client list without login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will **not** work as `/admin` has much further data access and actually each XSL transform will *only* work correctly for certain endpoints within `/admin`. Outside of that only the data from `/admin/stats` (XML) is available and it doesn't include sensitive data such as all client details. It is a bit more than is generally available in `status.xsl` by default though.

If you want to expose this information you could pass the request through a reverse proxy or process it explicitly inside a second web-server with a script like PHP, python, etc.

Please note that if you want information for a *specific* mount-point, then you can also use the *source* credentials of that mount to access certain endpoints within `/admin`. For details see documentation linked below.

Please also see:

- https://icecast.org/docs/icecast-2.4.1/server-stats.html
- https://icecast.org/docs/icecast-2.4.1/admin-interface.html